# Delayed Job: sending an email tomorrow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm using delayed job (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to send emails upon user signup. I want to delay the sending of the email for a day.

What's the easiest way to do this? The documentation for sending email is below:

```
# without delayed_job
Notifier.signup(@user).deliver

# with delayed_job
Notifier.delay.signup(@user)
```

Where can I pass a parameter to allow me to delay the email for a set period of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `:run_at` hash value on `delay()`.

```
Notifier.delay(:run_at => 1.day.from_now).signup(@user)
```